# Edit in Place initiates automatically when Dialog Box opened – Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog

I have an Angular app where the user can click on a button, opening a dialog box. On opening the dialog, I've put a `textarea` modified with the `contenteditable` attribute so the text can be edited in place.

`<textarea contenteditable>Click me to edit</textarea>`

The problem I am having is that when the dialog is opened, the editable text automatically opens in edit mode (as indicated by the colored line surrounding the `textarea` content, and the flashing input cursor). Any ideas why this is happening?

Stackblitz is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dialog-nwf9fi?file=app%2Fexample%2Fexample-dialog%2Fexample-dialog.component.html). Reproduce the problem simply by clicking on the "Open Dialog" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is this code:

```html
<textarea contenteditable>Click me to edit</textarea>
```

If you change textarea to div with a binding, like this:

```html
<div [contentEditable]="edit">
   Edit this content to add your own quote
</div>
```

Then the property is bindable.

```js
import { Component, Inject, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'example-dialog.component.html',
})
export class ExampleDialogComponent {
  // just use the input decorator here
  @Input("edit") edit:boolean = true;
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ExampleDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```